# Issues building Node.js v4 for ARM with software floating-point emulation

Tags: linux, node.js, arm

My team is developing a product on an embedded Linux OS running Node.js for the web back-end for device configuration. We're porting our code to a system with an arm processor that does not have a hardware FPU. (The previous product did have an FPU.) We've compiled Node.js with the following compiler options:

```
--with-arm-float-abi=soft
```

and

```
--with-arm-float-abi=softfp
```

But in both cases Node.js crashes at runtime with an illegal instruction because it's trying to do hardware floating-point. It seems to be in the V8 engine because we can run `node --version` and it prints the version and exits. I haven't checked the source but I presume it's not starting V8 just to print the version number.

Any idea what we're missing here? I could post the entire makefile if it would help, but it seems like noise for this issue. I'm hoping to find someone who has built Node.js (a version after 0.10) for an ARM processor that does not have hardware floating point and tell me what config/build options we might be missing. Or tell me the above option should work and we're just doing it wrong.

Comment: What is the processor, toolchain, and what Linux setup are you running this on?

Comment: Seems like stackoverflow would be a good place for this question, as it is a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved  by adding in the file *config.gypi* these two lines:

`'v8_can_use_fpu_instructions%': 'false',
'v8_use_mips_abi_hardfloat%': 'false',`

Comment: Were you building for MIPS or ARM? The options you mention are found in `deps/v8/build/toolchain.gypi` and the comments there say the options are for MIPS. Our target platform is ARM.

Comment: Actually, it was MIPS.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.